# Not able to deploy solution to Sitecore Docker instance 9.3.0

Tags: docker

I am trying to deploy solution to my sitecore docker instance. Below is solution mapping code

```
cm:
    image: ${REGISTRY}sitecore-xp-standalone:${SITECORE_VERSION}-windowsservercore-${WINDOWSSERVERCORE_VERSION}
    entrypoint: cmd "start /B powershell Watch-Directory C:\src C:\inetpub\sc"
    volumes:
      - .\deploy:C:\src
      - .\data\cm:C:\inetpub\sc\App_Data\logs
    ports:
      - "44001:80"
```

But, when I try to start the container I get below error message

```
Skipping start of 'Watch-Directory.ps1', to enable you should mount a directory into 'C:\src'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are using a legacy docker-compose file, probably used for an older version of Sitecore Docker images. In Sitecore Docker 9.2+ images, the web application files have been moved from the old `C:\inetpub\sc` folder to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder and new entrypoint scripts have been introduced as well.

To run Sitecore 9.3 images, you can use the `docker-compose.xp.yml` in the Sitecore Docker repository as example and starting point: https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/blob/master/windows/tests/9.3.x/docker-compose.xp.yml#L138

And then you should add the definition of your volumes (or bind mounts) in the `cm` container service:

```
volumes:
      - .\deploy:C:\src
      - .\data\cm:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs
```

The `Development.ps1` entrypoint script used in the `cm` container service starts the `Watch-Directory.ps1` script and also contains a retry logic to check and guarantee that the `Watch-Directory` script runs successfully.

```
entrypoint: powershell.exe -Command "& C:\\tools\\entrypoints\\iis\\Development.ps1"
```